# How do I see extra tags on a local Docker image?

Tags: docker

When I build a Docker image locally with a tag, then assign a secondary tag, I am unable to list all of the tags for that image.

I'm losing tags either on the build, save or load of docker images and I'm trying to track the state of my image at every step. Please note that this is a local Docker file (as in on my laptop), and can't be sent to a remote repository. When I run `docker images` I can see the image created with one of the tags, but not all of them.

```sh
$ docker build -t my/repo:first_tag
$ docker tag my/repo:first_tag my/repo:second_tag
```

When I run `docker images` I only see the first tag shown as *the* tag.

```sh
$ docker images
REPOSITORY     TAG          IMAGE ID     CREATED          SIZE
my/repo        first_tag    abcd1234     6 seconds ago    100MB
```

I would like to have some way of showing that image with all of the tags, something like:

```sh
my/repo:
  first_tag
  second_tag
```

Does a command like this exist and, if so, what is it?

**EDIT:** It turns out I was adding tags wrong and the code show above wasn't representative of it. What I was doing was actually:

```sh
$ docker build -t my/repo:first_tag
$ docker tag my/repo:first_tag my/repo
```

Note that the second tag doesn't have an actual tag on it. When I actually run the code in the question I get the following output:

```sh
$ docker images
REPOSITORY     TAG          IMAGE ID     CREATED          SIZE
my/repo        second_tag   abcd1234     6 seconds ago    100MB
my/repo        first_tag    abcd1234     6 seconds ago    100MB
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to list tags for a particular image, you can run :

```
docker images my/repo --format="{{ .Tag }}"
```

`--format` is used here to only keep interesting columns. By default, `docker images my/repo` will return all info about `my/repo` (repository, tag, image id, created and size), like `docker images` (without filtering repository) does.

**Edit** : group images by tags

Since `--format` option placeholders are limited (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#format-the-output), you cannot access some interesting properties as `.RepoTags` to retrieve all tags associated with an image digest. However, you could do this by `docker inspect`ing desired images and using some shell and [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) magic (`jq` is a tool to manipulate JSON) :

```
docker images my/repo --format="{{ .ID }}" | \
    sort | uniq | \
    xargs docker inspect | \
    jq -r '.[] | [ .Id, (.RepoTags | join(",")) ] | @csv'
```

Explanations :

- first, retrieve all images IDs (`--format="{{ .ID }}"`) related to `my/repo`
- remove duplicates (`sort | uniq`) if any (because of multiple tags per image ID)
- for each image (`xargs`), inspect that image (`docker inspect`) :

  - use `jq` to retrieve a string like `<id of the image>,<tags related to the image>`. Tags related to this image are separated by a comma (`join(",")`)

Example result :

```
"sha256:abcd1234...","my/repo:v1"
"sha256:abcd2345...","my/repo:v2"
"sha256:abcd3456...","my/repo:v3,my/repo:tag"
```

Comment: So is there a way of differentiating between multiple tags for different versions of an image, to multiple tags for a specific version of an image? So if I build an image (`my/repo:123`) and assign a second tag to it (`my/repo:456`), then build a second, different, image (`my/repo:789`), this will return `123`, `456` and `789`, despite two of those being for the same version of an image, and the third being for the second version of the image.

Comment: It's not possible to do this using the `--format` option, because placeholders are limited (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#format-the-output), so you can't access to `.RepoTags` property which contains all tags related to the image. However, you can `docker inspect` all your images to get that `.RepoTags` (see my updated answer).

Comment: Wow, thank you for the deep dive, really appreciated ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Get RepoTags by example:

```
docker image inspect my/backend:latest-qa | jq -r '.[] | (.RepoTags)'
ouput:
[
  "my/backend:0.12.3-qa",
  "my/backend:latest-qa"
]
```

Comment: in case some is wondering, `jq -r '.[] | .RepoTags'` is "get all the elements of the array and search in all of them the `RepoTags`, it's actually the same as `jq -r '.[].RepoTags'`.